# How to copy a file from jenkins workspace (linux server) to windows shared folder using jenkins pipeline?

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-directory

I was trying to copy a file from Linux to Windows shared folder using Jenkins Pipeline. Can you please share working step to resolve?

**Approach 1:**

`curl --upload-file /home/me/local_file.txt --user "OurWindowsDomain\UserName:thePassword" smb://172.16.17.52/ShareName/Path/To/Remote/Dir`

> Error : *Recv failure: Connection reset by peer 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0 * Closing connection 0 curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

**Approach 2:**

`smbclient //server/share -c 'cd c:/remote/path ; put local-file remote-file'`

> error: protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET

**Approach 3:**

SCP not working as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to ask good, detailed questions. That being said: What have you tried so far? Can you share your current approach?

Comment: approach 1
curl --upload-file /home/me/local_file.txt --user "OurWindowsDomain\UserName:thePassword" smb://172.16.17.52/ShareName/Path/To/Remote/Dir

 Error :
*Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Approach 2:
smbclient //server/share -c 'cd c:/remote/path ; put local-file remote-file'

error:
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET

Approach 3:
SCP  not working as well